# Raspbian : Force a wlan0 static ip

Tags: linux, networking, ip, debian, raspbian

I would like to configure a wlan0 static ip and  connect through it by ssh.

Here my `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
adress 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.100.102
netmask 255.255.255.0
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

When I do `ifconfig` my wlan0 and eth0 interfaces are correctly configured :

However, when I want to ssh my raspberry by wifi, my Wifi router give to my raspberry the ip : `192.168.100.116`.

How can I force my Wifi router to give `192.168.100.102` to my rapsberry pi ?
Moreover, My Wifi router give to my raspberry sometimes `192.168.100.102` and sometimes `192.168.100.116`

Don't know why

Answer (score 4):

I experienced similar issues when I wanted to connect my Rasperry Pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie Lite in a headless configuration for access using SSH from my Windows 10 PC with PuTTY.

In my case it turned out that the Ahavi daemon (an implementation of zeroconf) conflicted with the DHCP and name server options of my router.

Raspbian Jessie and Raspbian Jessie Lite comes pre-configured with an Avahi and a DHCP client deamon for automated network configuration. In most situation this will probably work fine, but if not, things take a turn for the worse with  unpredictable side-effects.

Instead of going too deep into any details (its really a long story) I will just summarize here what I did and why. There are too many possible issues and I dont want to push you into the wrong direction. Try it out. If it fails, look for another approach or leave a comment for clarification.

Now let's get your feet wet:

1. Try it first on a non-productive SD card with a fresh copy of Raspbian Jessie (for headless servers I prefer Raspbian Jessie Lite).
2. Start the Raspberry Pi with a keyboard and a monitor connected and login with user pi.
3. Start raspi-config with `sudo raspi-config` and make sure to turn on the SSH server (menue 7 Advanced Options -> A4 SSH).
4. Get your current IP address for `eth0` with `ifconfig`.
5. Try to connect to this address over ethernet using ssh. In case you cant connect, resolve this issue first. You cant connect over WLAN at this stage.
6. In case your connection succeeds, you can do the rest of your configuration using this connection over ssh.
7. Purge the avahi-daemon

   `$ sudo apt-get purge avahi-daemon`

Dont worry about the error message `'rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/run/avahi-daemon’: Directory not empty'.` This is related to a an empty socket and a pid file, that currently cannot be removed. You can ignore this message or remove the directory manually, but it wont hurt in case you just leave it.

```
$ sudo rm -r /var/run/avahi-daemon
```

8. Configure `/etc/network/interfaces`

It's important to know, that we need only one single change in this file. Open `/etc/network/interfaces` for changes with the editor of your choice (note: if you followed this steps 1:1 extended vim is not yet installed).

```
$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add the line `auto eth0` just before the existing line `iface eth0 inet manual`. That's all we have to do here is to here. After the changes the file should look like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Note: make sure to read and to understand the comments on top of the file!

9. Configure the DHCP client daemon

Next, as stated in the comments of the previously edited file, add the static ip configuration at the end of the configuration file for the DHCP client daemon.

It might sound silly to use a DHCP client if we are going to use static IP addresses anyway. However, when I tried to remove the DHCP client daemon I experienced new configuration and/or dependency issues. Finally I decided to keep as close to the standard configuration as possible and leave it as is.

The configuration is done at the very end in the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (watch proper spelling). The last line in the file should read: `'nohook lookup-hostname'`. So let's open the the file in the editor and scroll down to the bottom of the file.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

Add there the static ip definition. In my case the definitions at the of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` look like this:

```
nohook lookup-hostname

# static ip configuration for eth0 and wlan0
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.61/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.62/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Note that the syntax is different from the syntax used in `/etc/network/interfaces`. For a full class C network the netmask must be provided in form of a `/24` at the end of the IP address. For further details consult `man dhcpcd.conf`.

10. Reboot and test your configuration with eth0

After the next reboot you should have a reliable network configuration with static ip addresses. But remember, we are not yet finished and only eth0 will work. At this point even no IPv4 address will be shown for wlan0 if `ifconfig` is issued

In case it fails and you didn't do anything wrong so far (carefully check for typos), then you have another issue that must get fixed first; in this case this solution is probably not for you.

11. Configure WLAN

To configure WLAN we have to edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and add a network configuration to it.

In my case I'm using WPA/PSK for secure access and after modifying the country code and adding the network entry, the content of the file looks something like this:

```
country=CH
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
      
# home network; allow all valid ciphers
network={
    ssid="home"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="very secret passphrase"
}
```

`ssid="home"` is the WLAN network name (SSID) of the WLAN router or access point.

`scan_ssid=1` scans for hidden SSID's. This is usual practice but can slowdown the scan process.

`key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` defines that WPA pre-shared key management protocol will be used.

`psk="very secret passphrase"` defines your passphrase to access the router.

Replace the values assigned for ssid and psk with the real values for your secure WLAN access. There are several supported protocols, some requiring other and more options.

Consult `man wpa_supplicant.conf` for additional and more detailled information.

10. Reboot and test your configuration with wlan0

Now it's time to reboot and test wlan0. The ip address configured for wlan0 should now appear if `ifconfig` is issued.

If this is the case you should be able to access the Rasperry Pi using ssh with the IP address configured for wlan0.

I hope you are happy and everything works fine for you so far. If this is the case, I could stop writing here and leave you alone. But wait, there is more!

11. Two network connections, does that make sense?

If you connect to the Raspberry Pi from the same network over both, eth0 and wlan0 and issue an `ifconfig` to take a look at the transmitted and received packets or bytes, you will recognize, that even you connected to the IP for wlan0 most traffic is going through eth0.

I cant explain why this is the case, but obviously somehow the packets are routed along the faster path which sounds good so far.

However, I've seen rare situations where this behaviour was undesirable and slowed my connections down. Since I'm using my Raspberry Pi either near my router using a wired connection to eth0 or more distant from the router with no access to a cable using wlan0, I decided to stop wlan0 if a cable with an active connection to the router is attached to eth0.

To do this I created the script `/home/pi/ifdown-wlan-if-not-needed.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
#### Shutdown wlan0
# Test eth0 for a cable attached and
# shutdown wlan0 if this is the case.
###
sleep 30
cable=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier)
echo $cable
if [ "$cable" = "1" ]; then
   sudo ifdown wlan0
fi
exit 0
```

Then I've set the script to executable

```
$ chmod +x /home/pi/ifdown-wlan-if-not-needed.sh
```

And added it for execution after reboot with `crontab -e` to the crontab of user `pi`.

```
@reboot /home/pi/ifdown-wlan-if-not-needed.sh
```

12. Name to IP address resolution

So far I have not yet addressed the name to IP address resolution problem. How this can be done best, depends on your network equipment and use case.

My router provides the ability to bind names to MAC addresses, hostnames and IPv4 adresses. However, for some reason none of these options really work. Some times it works by simply using the given name, other times the suffix .home is needed. Sometimes the names disappear from the list or no name resolution takes place even everything looks ok.

I finally defined the adresses in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file of my Windows PC and my Notebook. This is certainly not state of the art but works reliable and without hassle.

However, I cant guarantee that what I did works for you too, but I hope it brings you on the right track to get your problem solved. I've been using my configuration since the release of Raspbian Jessie about one year ago. It survived any updates without hassle so far.

Good luck!

Comment: the eth0 interface has a higher priority than the wlan0 interface. The "metric" column of the "route" command shows it.

Answer (score 1):

Login on your router management interface and (if it has this feature, most do have it) reserve a DHCP address on the router for your selected client, so that the specific client always has the same IP address. See [this article](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1393495) for more information.